# Linq Results of Where to Object Collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've got a problem that I can work around, but I feel like there should be a solution within Linq that I'm just not seeing.

So I have two classes, a detail record class and a collection of those classes:

```
public class ItemDetail
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int? Id {get;set;}
}

public class ItemDetailCollection : List<ItemDetail>
{
}
```

Now, I can fill up those objects using my repository layer without a problem, and query the data to get the subset of records I want.

```
var items = Repository.GetItemCollection();
var reportItemCollection = items.Where(x => x.Id.HasValue);
```

This is all fine and dandy.  However, the `reportItemCollection` is an `IEnumerable<ItemDetail>`, and what I really want is a new `ItemDetailCollection`.

Of course, I could create a new collection and add the query range, but I feel like there is a way to automatically populate the result set as the specific collection type.  I've tried adding the following and only receive the results as `NULL`:

```
var reportItemCollection = items.Where(x=>x.Id.HasValue) as ItemDetailCollection;
```

And trying `.Cast<ItemDetailCollection>()` does not work either.  Finally, I've tried

```
var reportItemCollection = items.Where(x => x.Id.HasValue)
                                .Select(result => new ItemDetailCollection() { result });
```

but this only gives me an `IEnumerable<ItemDetailCollection>`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way is to actually construct the collection, using the constructor for `List<T>`:

```
public class ItemDetailCollection : List<ItemDetail>
{
    public ItemDetailCollection(IEnumerable<ItemDetail> items)
        : base(items) { }
}
```

And

```
var reportItemCollection = new ItemDetailCollection(
    items.Where(x=>x.Id.HasValue)
);
```

You can't cast an `IEnumerable<T>` to a subclass like `ItemDetailCollection`, due to the rules of covariance/contravariance (see here, for example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx).

Comment: In simpler terms: How would you solve the problem when your result is a `List<ItemDetail>`? By passing it to the `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor! (`.ToList()` is just a wrapper that calls that constructor)

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for - I was almost to the point of creating a custom constructor to do something like this but wanted to see if there was a straightforward way of doing this within Linq.  Since this is specific to only this class, I believe this constructor works perfectly!  And you make a great point @ScottChamberlain

Answer (score 4):

I would solve this the same way that LINQ solves it for `List<T>`: create a `ToItemDetailCollection` extension method

```
static ItemDataCollection ToItemDataCollection(this IEnumerable<ItemDetail> e) {
  return new ItemDataCollection(e);
}
```

Then you can just append this to any query

```
var reportItemCollection = items
  .Where(x=>x.Id.HasValue)
  .ToItemDataCollection();
```

On a separate note I would question why you are deriving from `List<T>` at all.  It offers no `virtual` methods to override and hence there is no possibility of customization.  Using this over `List<ItemDetail>` everywhere will just cause a lot of pain points like this one.

Comment: There is value to this if the collection object were to be used outside of a specific API, but honestly this is nothing more than a data object (or really a collection of data objects).  The reason I'm not using a List<ItemDetail> is simple: that's the standard for our data objects - if we need to add more information to the collections, we have that ability without having to change List<T> to a new class.

Comment: @brenton but what advantage does this provide?  It certainly will cause you pain (this question is a good example of that)